# Register/ Login/ Membership module in Orchard

Tags: orchardcms

I can't figure out how to add Register/Login functionality to a site in Orchard. Is there a Membership module or some configuration I need to enable?

EDIT: What I had in mind were modules along the lines of these that extend the existing User  model with registration/profile functionality: 
Extended Registration module: http://extendedregistration.codeplex.com/ 
Orchard Profile module: http://orchardprofile.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's under settings/users in the admin ui.

Comment: Thanks Bertrand, do I need to create new content types and a registration / login page? I'm new to Orchard and just getting familiar with some of the concepts. If you could point me to any documentation on how to implement or extend the membership functionality that would be great.

Comment: No, that's it. As for extensions, depends what you have in mind, but there are a few profile modules that can help.

Comment: @Brendan It doesn't seem  to be there in 1.7(RC). Any ideas where it is hiding now?

Comment: It's still there in 1.7. Staring at it.

Answer (score 0):

In the Dashboard scroll down to Settings and select Users.
Make sure "Users can create new accounts on the site" is checked and click "Save".
Once this is done log out.
Then click log in, and bellow your username and password field there will be a small text with a blue link to Register.

You don't actually need the extended registration and profile for this. Those are for adding additional information to the registration form.

This can also be done programmatically:

```
var registrationSettings = _services.WorkContext.CurrentSite.As<RegistrationSettingsPart>();
registrationSettings.UsersCanRegister = true;
```

However this will not work if you're doing it from Migrations because you won't be able to use WorkContext.
For migrations you can use IRepository for RegistrationSettingsPartRecord:

```
RegistrationSettingsPartRecord currentSetting = _registrationSettingRepository.Table.First();
currentSetting.UsersCanRegister = true;
_registrationSettingRepository.Update(currentSetting);
```

**However** this will no longer work as of Orchard version 1.8 as the record no longer exists. As of 1.8 one way I know of would be using ISiteService:

```
var site = _siteService.GetSiteSettings();
var regsettings = site.As<RegistrationSettingsPart>();
regsettings.UsersCanRegister = true;
```